# How to remove the FIRST whitespace from a python dataframe on a certain column

Tags: python-3.x

I extracted a pdf table using `tabula.read_pdf` but some of the data entries a) show a whitespace between the values and b) includes two sets of values into one column as shown one columns "Sports 2019/2018" and "Total 2019/2018": https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2cpl.jpg

In order for me to use `df_1=df1["Sprots 2019/2018"].str.split(expand=True)` to split the two values which are separated by a space, I need to remove the FIRST space shown in the first value so that it doesn't split into three columns.

I've tried `df1["Sports 2019/2018"] = df1["Sports 2019/2018"].str.replace(" ", "")` but this removes all the spaces, which would then combine the two values.

Is there a way to remove the first whitespace on column "Sports 2019/2018 so that it resembles the values on "Internet 2019/2018'?

Comment: can you clarify the question more - it is hard to see from the picture what you mean. To remove whitespace from the left of a string, use lstrip().

Comment: for instance, on column "Sports 2019/2018" index 2, the value shows up as "4 96,660 $- n/a"...but I need it to show up as "496,660 $- n/a".

Comment: if you check the documentation of the replace method, you will see that you can specify the number of replacements to make: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html. Try df1["Sports 2019/2018"] = df1["Sports 2019/2018"].str.replace(" ", "", 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1["Sports 2019/2018"] = df1["Sports 2019/2018"].str.replace(" ", "", n = 1)
```

n=1 is an argument that will ***only replace the first character*** that will find.